# When building a shared library, are only the header files of dependent libraries needed?

Tags: build, shared-libraries

Say a shared library *A* depends on another shared library *B*.

In this case, when I build *A*, do I need only the header file of *B*?
Because *B* is only needed when I build some program that needs *A*. Is it right? Could you explain the details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. Here is a concrete illustration.

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

extern void aa(void);

#endif
```

**a.c**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

void aa(void)
{
    bb();
}
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

extern void bb(void);

#endif
```

**b.c**

```
#include "b.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void bb(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "a.h"

int main(void)
{
    aa();
    return 0;
}
```

We make a shared library `liba.so`. First compile a [PIC (Position Independent)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)
object file.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o a.o -c -fPIC a.c
```

Now the object file `a.o` contains an undefined reference to `bb`:

```
$ readelf -s a.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
   ...
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bb
```

Link the shared library:

```
$ gcc -shared -o liba.so a.o
```

Now the shared library also makes an undefined reference to `bb`:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms liba.so

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 12 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
   ...
     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bb
   ...
```

That is fine. *The linker will create a shared library containing undefined references*.

Make another shared library `libb.so` in the same way:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o b.o -c -fPIC b.c
$ gcc -shared -o libb.so b.o
```

This shared library defines `bb`:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms libb.so

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 12 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
   ...
    11: 000000000000060a    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 bb
```

Next try to make a program:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main.o -c main.c
$ gcc -o prog main.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `aa'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That's what happens when we link with neither `liba` nor `libb`. The linker will
not create a *program* containing undefined references. So:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o liba.so
liba.so: undefined reference to `bb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

that's what happens when we link with `liba` but not `libb`. If we link with
both, like:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o liba.so libb.so
```

Success! But take care. If we swap the order of the libraries:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libb.so liba.so
liba.so: undefined reference to `bb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the linkage fails again. And so does:

```
$ gcc -o prog libb.so liba.so main.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `aa'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker needs to see a libary *after* other
libraries or object files that depend on it. So `main.o` must be linked before `liba`,
and `liba` must be linked before `libb`.

*And one last snag*.

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o liba.so libb.so
```

or equivalently:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -la -lb
```

successfully links the program `prog`, but:

```
$ ./prog
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: liba.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

it doesn't *run*. Because the runtime loader still doesn't know where to look for `liba` or `libb`

The loader knows that `prog` needs some shared libraries called `liba.so` and `libb.so` because the linker has written that
information into `prog`:

```
$ readelf -d prog

Dynamic section at offset 0xda8 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liba.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libb.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 ...
```

Just like the linker, there are [directories where the loader will search for shared libraries by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367682/89291).
It will find `libc.so.6` (the GNU C Library) in one of those default directories. But it won't find the `liba.so` or `libb.so` that I've
just built in any of them.

But I can tell the linker to provide the missing information for the loader, by linking
the program instead like this:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -la -lb -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

With `-Wl,-rpath=$PWD`, I'm telling `gcc` to pass the (expanded) option `-rpath=$PWD`
to the linker, and if we do that we'll see:

```
$ readelf -d prog

Dynamic section at offset 0xd98 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liba.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libb.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/scrap1]
 ...
```

So now when the loader loads `prog`, it will see that the `RUNPATH=/home/imk/develop/so/scrap1`
is a non-default directory where it should also search for any `NEEDED` shared libraries. `prog`
and all its runtime dependencies can then be successfully loaded:

```
$ ./prog
bb
```

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer :)